# #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

I was looking at a program that calculates the average of 3 numbers and came across

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
```

to make `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` work without an error (right under the include header). What is the purpose of using `#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` and is there any alternative to this? Is it like `return 0;`? Thank you for your time.

Here is the code for the program I was looking at:

```
#include <iostream>
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// prototypes:

float add_and_div(float, float, float);

// variables:

float x, y, z;
float result;

cout << "Enter three floats: ";
cin >> x >> y >> z;

// continue the program here

result = add_and_div( x, y, z );
cout<< "Average is \n" << result;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// function definition:

float add_and_div(float n1, float n2, float n3)
{

// continue the program here
return ( n1 + n2 + n3 ) / 3;
}
```

Comment: That's horrible. Just `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: That's horrible. Just `return 0;` :-)

Comment: That's horrible. Just fall off the end of `main()` because `return 0;` is implicit.

Answer (score 6):

The macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` expand into integral expressions that either indicate successful or unsuccessful execution of the program. They're part of the C standard and can be found in [`stdlib.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) or rather [`cstdlib`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status).

In your case it will expand to `0`, so `return EXIT_SUCCESS` **is** the same as `return 0`. However, the macro is already defined in the standard library, so you should use that one instead of defining your own. Note that returning or using `EXIT_SUCCESS` in `exit` will have the same behavior as using `0` at those occurrences, so it's up to you what you want to use.

Comment: This answer is correct, however you should also mention that, although `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not necessarily zero, returning zero from `main` (or calling `exit(0)`) is required by the C standard to do the same thing as returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @Zack: My answer was a little bit misleading, as one could read that that `0` isn't a valid indicator for success. I removed that part and included your information.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined in `<cstdlib>`. Presumably the author was simply unaware of this. Moreover it is *not* guaranteed to be zero, but an "integer constant expression that can be used as the argument to the `exit` function to return … successful termination status … to the host environment." (C11 §7.22/3) Therefore the compiler can complain about the custom `#define` conflicting with the macro definition in `<cstdlib>`.

In practice, it is always zero though. Even if it's not, zero is also guaranteed to mean success.

It's a matter of style, but most prefer to write no `return` statement at all at the end of `main`. In both C++ and recent editions of C, a `return 0;` is added automatically in this case.

Comment: ITYM `return 0;` rather than `return;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Woops, I was actually under the impression that `return;` was a third permissible case. Looked it up; it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the same. #define basically tells the compiler to switch,when they are referred, with it's value.

Example:

Code:

```
#define HELLO 0
#define WORLD "WORLD"

cout << HELLO;
cout << WORLD;
```

The compiler will then change it to:

```
cout << 0;
cout << "WORLD";
```

It's much more safe to use defines because you can easily change one value that changes the whole program than changing the whole program directly.

Also, defines are constant values. It also does not matter if it's an integer value, float, string or even a structure reference. And, because of being constant, defines can never be changed after the program execution (like in functions).

Answer (score 1):

As per `C++11 3.6.1 Main function /5`:

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) *and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument.*

In `18.5 Start and termination /8`, it states, with regards to `exit`:

> If status is _zero or EXIT_SUCCESS,_ an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

In other words, returning either `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` has the same effect here so you would be better off returning the literal `0`, which every competent C or C++ coder knows indicates a successful termination of the program.

If you *really* want to use `EXIT_SUCCESS`, you should be including the one in `<cstdlib>` rather than creating your own. The standard *specifically disallows* otherwise, as per `17.6.4.3.1 Macro names /1`:

> A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in *any* standard library header.

The fact that you're including a standard header file `iostream` means that you are not permitted to define `EXIT_SUCCESS` yourself.

Comment: Defining your own actually causes undefined behaviour (all macros that could be defined by the standard library are considered to be reserved, even if you don't include their header).